# How to run Orchard Core with IIS

Tags: c#, .net-core, orchardcore

How do I run [Orchard Core](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore) in IIS on my local machine. I am able to run the site by using dotnet run, but every time I create a new site in IIS with the physical path OrchardCore\src\OrchardCore.Cms.Web, I get a 403 error. I added IIS in the security tab and gave it full permission but I am not sure how to continue.

Answer (score 2):

Hey to run your site in IIS you'll need to do the following

- Install [.NET Core hosting bundle](https://www.microsoft.com/net/permalink/dotnetcore-current-windows-runtime-bundle-installer) on the server.
- Run the following in an elevated terminal `net stop was /y` (stops IIS).
- Run the following in an elevated terminal `net start w3svc` (start IIS).
- Run `dotnet publish --configuration Release` in your project root.
- Copy the output `bin/Release/{TARGET FRAMEWORK}/publish` to you IIS physical path.

Official docs are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=netcore-cli). If you need more help, there are also different ways of hosting .net core apps, In-process vs Out-of-process hosting.